# Not Iterating Over Characters in String

Tags: python, loops

Say I type the word "monty". the list should then contain ['m', 'o','n','t','y'] but instead it contains 5 copies of 'monty'. What am I doing wrong?

```
x = input("Give us a word and I will supply all possible anagrams: ")

list = []

for letter in x:
    list.append(x)


print(list)
```

Comment: in `list.append(x)` you are appending `x` instead of `letter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, it is told to do so.

Rather than,

```
for letter in x:
    list.append(x) <------------ Adding string itself to list, not a character
```

Do:

```
for letter in x:
    list.append(letter)
```

N.B. You can just do `lst = list(x)` to achieve the same thing. And, don't name your variables with the same name as builtin types(list, dict, tuple etc.)